# Determine what parent element a given element is inheriting a css property from

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I'm refactoring they styling of a page with complex css inheritances. I've been spending a lot of time inspecting an element in chrome and looking through the styles backtrace. I'd like a function or library that allows me to supply an element and a css property and have it return the parent that css rule is inherited from.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #foo {
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="foo">
    <div id="bar">hi</div>
</div>
    <script>

        $('#bar').someFunction('width'); //returns #foo

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't have an answer but if you go to the "Elements/Computed" tab it will tell you where the property is being set/overrided

Comment: @DavidNguyen Thanks that's really useful. I'm not sure if this is an issue that can be solved with javascript so I was looking for chrometools that would accomplish the same thing as well.

Comment: Your example shouldn't be returning `#foo`. `#bar` is a block element, so it's width will be `auto`, which will render it `100%` of it's parents width. If you'd inherit the width (`width: inherit;`) you'll want to return `#foo`. But that's what the Chrome dev tools will show you as well.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow